# Не могу запустить gulp. В чем проблема?

Tags: javascript, gulp

уважаемые специалисты! Проблема непонятная. Верстаю сайты с использованием Gulp. Использую одну и ту же сборку. Сегодня создал новый проект в VS Code, распаковал туда сборку как обычно, как всегда npm install, npm run dev, но в этот раз вылезла ошибка file:///C:/Web/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0/config/gulp-

```
tasks/reset.js:1
import del from "del";
       ^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'del' does not provide an export named 'default'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:128:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
```

Что надо делать не пойму, ничего из сборки не удалял и не менял, готовые проекты на этой сборке запускаются. Есть у кого идеи? Поделитесь, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замени код в файле reset.js на этот:

```
import {deleteAsync} from "del"
export const reset = () => {
    return deleteAsync(['dist'])
}
```

Там, где 'dist' - путь к папке с файлами. У меня это 'dist/files', т.к. файлы лежат в папке files.

С тебя пиво)

Answer (score 0):

Замени в файле package.json версию плагина:
"del": "latest" на
**"del": "^6.1.1"**